# Django ORM: filtering on calculated fields MySQL status/workaround

Tags: django, django-orm

It seems that Django developers are aware about the fact that there's no way to filter on calculated fields like this in MySQL:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={ 'total': 'SOME CALCULATION GOES HERE' }, where=['total < 10'])
```

OR

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={ 'total': 'SOME CALCULATION GOES HERE' }).filter(total__lt=10)
```

This was described in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8784 but unfortunately it looks like it will take another year to implement with current speed. I understand the concern of development team that ideally they want to get rid of the .extra() because by writing pure SQL in that statement code becomes non DB-agnostic. I believe that dealing with calculated field is fairly common task in many projects and I currently faced the problem that I can't solve: I think the majority of community often uses this dirty workaround:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={ 'total': 'SOME CALCULATION GOES HERE' }, where=['1 HAVING total < 10'])
```

and in fact it works, but only till the moment when you need to add filter on the result of the statement above:

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={ 'total': 'SOME CALCULATION GOES HERE' }, where=['1 HAVING total < 10']).filter(id__gt=300)
```

this doesn't work anymore, because it translates to the wrong SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, ..., (SOME CALCULATION) AS total
FROM some_table
WHERE (1 AND HAVING total < 10 AND id > 300)
```

What I want to achieve is to have some kind of restriction in custom model manager which would allow me to write code like this:

```
class SomeModelManager(models.Manager):
  def apply_total_restriction(self, restriction_num):
    return self.extra(select={ 'total': 'CALCULATION GOES HERE' }).filter(total__lt=restriction_num)

...

SomeModel.objects.apply_total_restriction(restriction_num).filter(created_by_id__exact=1)
```

Question is: does anybody know how to overcome this temporary (hopefully) restriction and to fulfill the task? Any possible alternatives?

Comment: Is for you a solution materialize this field ( in save method for example ) and write condition over materialized data? This also will improve performance.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option - in fact what I have in the project is much more complicated then the truly naive example above and I can't save that calculated field into DB, because its value is calculated with some input data which differs for particular user and only known during run time. Though I admit that your solution would work for simpler scenarios.

Comment: @Ivan: Show us what kind of calculation are you trying to do. Is it some kind of aggregation or just computation on the model fields. There could be simpler solutions depending on the calculation type.

Comment: OK, imagine that there's the model SomeModel with several fields like title, description, somelocation_id (FK to the next SomeLocationModel) etc. and there's another model SomeLocationModel with fields like latitude, longitude, name and so forth. I'm trying to get SomeModel and  to add to it new "distance" field which equals to calculated geographical distance to the corresponding SomeLocationModel from the current user using geo location and Haversine formula to calculate the distance and also to filter after adding that distance field to return only records which are within 10 km radius.

Comment: The code I'm currently using and which is not perfect, because as I said above I can't add .filter(...) to QuerySet because the outcome query would be completely wrong is the following: self.select_related('place').extra(select={
           'distance': 'round((6371 * acos(cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(%s)) + sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(latitude)))), 3)'
       }, select_params=[latitude, longitude, latitude], where=['1 HAVING distance < %s'], params=[radius])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: I thought it will be too slow to calculate that field again in WHERE clause, but when I've tried it it turned to be quite fast and no HAVING required. Below is the demonstration of what I meant:

`SELECT (a + b / 2) as 'c', a, b
FROM table
WHERE (a + b / 2) >= 20 AND a != b`

That's basically it - if you think you need HAVING, try to measure time with HAVING and compare it to time with calculating calculated field again and filter by it in WHERE and then make a conclusion.